# Как защититься от скриптов в jQuery.html()?

Tags: jquery

Пример:

```
container.html(code);
```

Если в `code` будет записано `<script>alert('!!!');</script>`, то этот `alert` покажется.

Как сделать, чтобы скрипты не выполнялись, но при этом по-прежнему выполнялись html тэги. Т.е. если `code = "<b>a</b><script>alert('!!!');</script>"`, то появится

**a**<script>alert('!!!');</script>

Comment: Вам нужно, что остальные теги работали, или достаточно будет того, что они просто текстом будут выводиться?

Comment: нужно, чтобы работали

Comment: @ruslan5t как на мой взгляд - тут парсер надо собирать. Я попробую что-нибудь узнать, но мне кажется, что всё сводится к парсеру. :(

Comment: есть много способов выполнить js без `<script>`, вот например `<div onclick="alert(1)">многа вкуснаго</div>` <div onclick="alert(1)">тест</div>

Comment: Есть ф-я [`jQuery.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/), которая умеет убирать скрипты, но **нельзя** полагаться только на неё полностью.

В её описании есть ещё один способ вставить-таки скрипт: `<img onerror=`

Answer (score 1):

### PHP

---

в начало страницы

```
ob_start("repl");
```

подключаем функцию:

```
function repl($buffer) {
$arr = array(
'onclick',
'onerror',
'onload',
'onmouseover'
);
    $buffer = preg_replace("/\<script(\stype=\"text\/javascript\")?\>(.*)\<\/script\>/", "", $buffer);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $buffer = preg_replace("/".$value."=\"(.*)\"/", "", $buffer);
    }
    return $buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Как насчёт `onerror()`? А может, что-то ещё упустили?

Comment: Код представлен на PHP, а не на JS

Comment: @bazaev05, @sergiks имеет в виду то, что, например, в img onerror="" можно указать js-код, который выполнится при невозможности загрузить изображение (как в onclick, который вы указали)

Comment: отредактировал ответ, добавил onerror

Comment: @bazaev05 onload, onmouseover, onмногочтоещё ссылка на javascript:// еще есть, в коде выше - iframe.

Comment: @eicto, переделал. это для граббера нужно?

Comment: @bazaev05 я намекаю что перебором мало толку.

Comment: @eicto, если это для граббера то можно просто посмотреть в нескольких страницах какие методы используются и их прописать для замены. Ведь не будут же все способы использоваться на одном сайте? То есть, это редкость.

Comment: обычно, это используется для фильтрации контента вводимого пользователем.

Answer (score 0):

Например, проверяйте регуляркой на соотвествие тем операторам, которые вы допускаете, а остальные обрамляйте тегами `<pre></pre>`

Comment: А комментарии? А HTML entity? А блоки CDATA? Парсить HTML регулярками уже давно не смешно.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка есть какая-нибудь дефолтная функция, но

```
var text = "<b>a</b><script>alert('!!!');</script>"
text.replace(new RegExp('<(/?)script>', 'gi'), '&lt;$1script&gt;');
// <b>a</b>&lt;script&gt;alert('!!!');&lt;/script&gt;
```

Можно даже не прибегать к регэкспам, используя некрасивый код

```
text.replace('<script>', '&lt;script&gt;').replace('</script>', '&lt;/script&gt;');
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` пройдёт.

Comment: @sergiks Цитата:

    <script type="text/javascript"> пройдёт.
А что мешает добавить в исключения и его? Сделать парсер, скажем так, на несколько условий.

Comment: @intro94: например, тем, что придётся делать полноценный парсер, а это не так уж просто.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `innerHTML` и будет вам счастье: `$(..).prop('innerHTML', code);`

P.S. Для 100% гарантии от "<node on*=".."/>" можно сделать так: http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/aR65C/

Comment: @RubaXa: Неплохо. Но: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYuvq/3/

Comment: Не понял, что не так, ваш пример сломан. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gxcqdz6j5z53id/Screenshot%202014-02-26%2016.28.05.png
http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/aR65C/3/ — вот пример чтобы побаловаться

Comment: @VladD, в этом случае нужно вводить «белый список» тегов, что тоже не проблема.

Comment: @RubaXa: странно, в FF всё работает.

А, понял. Вам надо не <http://jsfiddle.net/ZYuvq/2/>, а <http://jsfiddle.net/ZYuvq/3/>

Comment: @VladD, я уже выше ответил, «белый список тегов» самый верный путь.